# sql - get the latest date of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, compare

```
table1
    - date1 datetime not null
    - date2 nvarchar null
```

I want to get the latest date of this two.

```
select date1, date2, 
(CASE WHEN date1 > CAST(date2 as DateTime) THEN date1 ELSE date2 END) as DateTime) as LatestDate
from table1
```

please note that date2 can be `null`. in this case, date1 win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date1, date2,  
CASE 
  WHEN date1 > CAST(ISNULL(date2,'1900-01-01') as DateTime) THEN 
     date1 
  ELSE 
    CAST(date2 as DateTime) 
END  as LatestDate 
FROM table1
```

Comment: How can I use it in update query? the update will be put the grate value in a new column.

Answer (score 1):

change `CAST(date2 as DateTime)` to `CAST(isnull(date2,'01/01/1900') as DateTime)`

Answer (score 0):

This is very nice solution, but I suspect [Nathan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917786/sql-get-the-latest-date-of-two-columns/2917826#2917826) is better.

http://p2p.wrox.com/oracle/6592-calculate-de-max-value-two-columns.html